# Django: Error during template rendering

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to build a feedback form but i am getting this error:
**Could not parse the remainder: '% csrf_token %' from '% csrf_token %'**

Here is my views.py:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=ContactForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
            topic=form.cleaned_data['topic']
            message=form.cleaned_data['message']
            sender=form.cleaned_data.get('sender')
            send_mail(
            'Feedback from your site,topic:%s'%topic,
            message,
            sender,
            ['jpahultiwari@gmail.com']
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
    else:
        form=ContactForm()
    context={'form':form}
    return render(request,'blog/contact.html',context)
```

Here is my template contact.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Feedback Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Contact Us</h1>
<form  action="." method="post" >
{{% csrf_token %}}
<table>{{form.as_table}}</table>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this answer helped you mark it as accepted. It's a good practice in StackOverflow to do so.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay in accepting your answer.Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typo there:

Change this `{{% csrf_token %}}` to this `{% csrf_token %}`

However, these kind of errors can easily be discovered by your side since Django's traceback is very detailed and points to the line of what caused the error.

Best regards!